# TypeError: object of type 'map' has no len()

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am using the function below to compute inverse term frequencies.

```
all_tokens_set = set([item for sublist in tokenized_documents for item in sublist]) 

def inverse_document_frequencies(tokenized_documents):
idf_values = {}
global dfInv
dfInv = pd.DataFrame() 
tokenized_documents = [tokenize(d) for d in words]
all_tokens_set = set([item for sublist in tokenized_documents for item in sublist])
for tkn in all_tokens_set:
    contains_token = map(lambda doc: tkn in doc, tokenized_documents)
    idf_values[tkn] = 1 + math.log(len(tokenized_documents)/(sum(contains_token))) 
dfInv=pd.DataFrame(data ={'tkn':contains_token,'idf_values':idf_values[tkn]})
return dfInv
inverse_document_frequencies(total_all)
```

`total_all` is a list.

I am getting the error message that:

> TypeError: object of type 'map' has no len()

Answer (score 1):

In order to find the length, you will have to type-cast the map to list (or tuple) and then you may call len over it. For example:

```
 >>> len(list(map(lambda a: a[0], x)))
3
```

Comment: That's not type casting, you're *consuming* the iterator.

Comment: Yeah I mean we need an instance of iterator to find the length so we are just converting it into list. I meant that